# How do I create a list of ranked numbers in Sheets––one that will adjust if I change a number?

Tags: google-sheets

I have a column of numbers 1-50 in a Google Sheet, which are a ranking list for a different column of fifty items (items are ranked relative to one another, so 1 is the best in the list and 50 is the worst; there are no repeats). I want to create a formula that will automatically adjust the list if I change the ranking of an item. For example, if I change one item's ranking from 25 to 30, I want the rankings 26-30 to automatically shift and become 25-29 (while still assigned to the same item they originally were). Are there existing functions I can use to do this?

Comment: Welcome. Please read how to and [share a test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311) so as you can be easier helped.

Comment: Welcome. Have you tried the `RANK.EQ` formula? This will automatically adjust all the rankings if you modify any score. It is not clear from your question whether you expect the ranks to be merely recalculated, or whether you expect the entire table to be re-sorted according to the rankings. In the latter case, `RANK.EQ` combined with `QUERY` (ordered on the rank column) might suit.

Comment: Thank you so much! I wasn't aware of the RANK.EQ function, that was definitely very helpful. I'm not too sure how to use QUERY, but I wanted a list like the one described in the latter part of your example (and most importantly with no repeat numbers). My raw data was in column C, beginning in row 2, and this is what I used: =ArrayFormula(if(len(C2:C),array_constrain(sort({row(C2:C)-1,sort({row(C2:C)-1,C2:C},2,true)},2,true),9^9,1),))